# Remove table row + DB row using AJAX/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have created a table which dynamically creates rows + a delete button everytime you add a row (the rows are read from the DB).

I want the delete button to remove the row and remove the DB data.

Here is my code:

**Ajax call:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this); 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'ajaxManager.php',
            data: 'idDel=' + $this.attr('id'),
            success: function() {
                $this.closest("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**ajaxManager:**

```
$name=filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'idDel', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_NULL_ON_FAILURE);
if($name !== FALSE) {
    $result = deletePlayer($db, $name);
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

**deletePlayer Function:**

```
function deletePlayer(PDO $conn, $name) {
    $sql = "delete from player where name = :name";
    try {
        $conn->beginTransaction();
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(":name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $conn->commit();
        $players = getPlayerInfo($conn);
    } catch (PDOException $exc) {
        echo $exc->getMessage();
    }
 return $players;
}
```

The button is able to delete the row from the table, but it is not deleting the row from the DB.

What is wrong? :(

Thanks in advance!

Edit: the table name in the DB is called "player", the column inside is called "name".

Comment: I see you are sending the id in the ajax but in the SQL i see you deleting by name are you sure the name in the SQL is equal to the id in the ajax

Comment: the table name in the SQL DB is "name", do I have to change the ajax to name as well?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I got it mixed up - the table is called player, the column inside the player is called name.

Comment: exactly, so the question now is
are you sure that the value [$this.attr('id')] in the ajax passed to the column name or there is another column called id in the table?

Comment: your query may look like:

    delete from player where id = :id

Comment: the value from [$this.attr('id')] is the name itself (I will post the code now for the button), and yes, there is another column called ID in the table but I dont think im using that.
<?php  echo "<button id=".$name1." type=\"button\">Delete</button>";

$name1 is the name when a new table is added, so the id of the button beside that name is the name as well

Comment: An example of the button code in the browser after render, please.

Comment: <button id="samer" type="button">Delete</button>

This would be an example of a button after the page has loaded, with the button's ID being the name from the DB (I have copied it directly from the inspect functionality in the browser)

Comment: try to pass the data as object like this:

 data: { idDel = $this.attr('id') }

Comment: Nope it won't work.. the table row also isn't deleted with this edit

Comment: what is the error in the console?

Comment: instead of :name you should delete by idDel variable, coj in ajax you are sending id in this parameter.

Comment: handle the ajax error and see what is the error the server is returning.

Comment: I am not getting any errors at the console when I click on the button